# Laravel select models based on relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a library application and I want to create a function where the user can rent out a book to a customer. However, I want the books that are rented out right now to not show up in the select box when renting out another book.
I have looked up several articles about this, but couldn't really make up a solution so I would be happy about any help.
The idea is, that when a book has the attribute "maxreturndate" set it won't show up.

**CheckedOutController:**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\CheckedOut;
    use App\Book;
    use App\Reader;



    class CheckedOutController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $checkedOuts = CheckedOut::with(['book', 'reader'])->get();

            return view('checkedouts/index', compact('checkedOuts'));
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            $books = Book::all();
            $readers = Reader::all();

            return view('checkedouts/create', compact('books','readers'));
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'book_id' => 'required',
                'reader_id' => 'required',
                'maxreturndate' => 'required|date',
                'returndate' => 'nullable',
                ]);

                $checkedOut = CheckedOut::create($validatedData);

                return redirect('checkedouts')->with('success', 'Buch wurde erfolgreich verliehen!');
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title')
<title>Alle ausgeliehen Bücher</title>
@section('content')
<style>
  .uper {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
</style>
<div class="uper">
  @if(session()->get('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('success') }}
  </div><br />
  @endif

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Titel</td>
        <td>Verliehen an</td>
        <td>Verleihdatum</td>
        <td>Fällig am</td>
        <td>Zurückgebracht am</td>
        <td colspan="2">Funktionen</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($checkedOuts as $checkedOut)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$checkedOut->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$checkedOut->book->title}}</td>
        <td>{{$checkedOut->reader->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$checkedOut->created_at}}</td>
        <td >{{$checkedOut->maxreturndate}}</td>
        <td>{{$checkedOut->returndate}}</td>
        <td></td>

        <td><a href="{{ route('checkedouts.edit', $checkedOut->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Bearbeiten</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('checkedouts.show', $checkedOut->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Anzeigen</a></td>
        <td>
          <form action="{{ route('checkedouts.destroy', $checkedOut->id)}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Löschen</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    @endsection
```

**Migrations:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCheckedOutsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('checked_outs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('book_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('reader_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('reader_id')->references('id')->on('readers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->date('maxreturndate');
            $table->date('returndate')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('checked_outs');
    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title')
<title>Buch verleihen</title>
@section('stylesheets')
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@endsection
@section('content')
<style>
    .uper {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div class="card uper">
    <div class="card-header">
        Buch verleihen
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('checkedouts.store') }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                @csrf
                <label for="book_id">Buch:</label>
                <select name="book_id" class="form-control select2-single <!-- @error('book_id') is-invalid @enderror -->">
                    @foreach ($books as $book)
                    <option value="{{ $book->id }}">{{ $book->title }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @error('book_id')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reader_id">Verleihen an:</label>
                <select name="reader_id" class="form-control select2-single <!-- @error('reader_id') is-invalid @enderror -->">
                    @foreach ($readers as $reader)
                    <option value="{{ $reader->id }}">{{ $reader->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @error('reader_id')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="maxreturndate">Zurückbringen bis:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="maxreturndate" />
                @error('name')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verleihen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".select2-single").select2();
</script>

@endsection
```

**The relationship between the 3 Models:**

Book:

```
public function checkedOut(){
    return $this->hasOne(CheckedOut::class);
}
```

Reader:

```
public function checkedOut()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CheckedOut::class);
    }
```

CheckedOut:

```
public function book(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);

}

public function reader(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Reader::class);

}
```

Comment: What are the relationships here between books and readers? Looks like many-to-many relationship with `checked_outs` as a pivot table?

Comment: Its just a one-to-one relationships, I did not want to make it too complicated this time. Basically one reader can check out one book at one time.

Comment: Can you update the question with relationship info for the three models? By introducing `CheckedOut` as a model and making it a pivot table (but not really) you've made it more complicated than it needs to be!

Comment: I updated it! Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: So your `readers` table has a `checked_out_id` column?

Comment: No, my checkedouts table has a reader_id column.

Comment: When you set up a `belongsTo()` relationship on a model, there's an expectation that it's the "child" and will have a column containing its parent's ID. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: But I think my answer should put this in a better place as far as the relationships go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to set up `Books` and `Readers` with a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Now, your models could look like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Book extends Model
{
    public function readers()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(\App\Reader::class, 'checked_outs')
            ->using(\App\Checkout::class)
            ->withPivot(['returndate', 'maxreturndate']);
    }
}

class Reader extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(\App\Book::class, 'checked_outs')
            ->using(\App\Checkout::class)
            ->withPivot(['returndate', 'maxreturndate']);
    }
}

class Checkout extends Pivot
{
    // this should be named `book_reader` but we override it here
    $table = "checked_outs";

    $dates = [
        "maxreturndate",
        "returndate",
    ];
}
```

I have [created a pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) which isn't necessary, but allows you to operate directly on the pivot table and cast the extra attributes to dates automatically. Whether this is useful is a matter of opinion. You should rename the `checked_outs` table to `book_reader` which is the naming convention that Laravel expects for a pivot table.

Getting the books that aren't checked out is simple enough to do as follows, using the [`doesntHave` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) to check for absence of a relationship.

```
public function create()
{
    $books = Book::doesntHave("readers")->get();
    $readers = Reader::all();

    return view('checkedouts/create', compact('books','readers'));
}
```

And "checking out" a book could look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $reader = Reader::find($request->reader_id);
    $reader
        ->books()
        ->attach(
            $request->book_id,
            ["returndate" => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(7)]
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So basically I do not even need the CheckedOut model, right? But I can still use the CheckedOutController and put the create function there if I understand correctly? Also I thought pivot tables are made up of 2 tables that are merged, so in this case it would be called books_readers, but apparently you can use custom names as well? Sorry and thanks for your answer in advance!

Comment: There's usually not a need to create a model for your pivot table. It can help with things like in the example above, where I use it to cast the date attributes. As I mention above, the default name for the pivot table is `book_reader` but you can override it.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to change my application, but I can't figure out how to output the data from the pivot table on my index page now. I have updated my question with my index page. Could you please help me with this one last thing?

Comment: Use the `pivot` property, e.g. `$book->pivot->returndate`. It's in the documentation under "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns"

Comment: I've tried several times, but I just can't display my data. I have asked on a different thread, could you maybe take a look at it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692595/displaying-pivot-table-data-in-laravel-6

Answer (score 0):

> when a book has the attribute "maxreturndate" set it won't show up

Since you did not specify in your migration, I am going to assume here that you have a `maxreturndate` nullable field in your `books` table, then you should be able to simply create a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes) when you want your list of "not rented" books.

Here's an example on creating a `notRented` scope:

```
// in your Book model define the local scope
public function scopeNotRented($query){
    return $query->whereNotNull('maxreturndate');
}

// in the create method of your controller
public function create()
{
    $books = Book::notRented()->get();
    $readers = Reader::all();

    return view('checkedouts/create', compact('books','readers'));
}
```

Comment: @miken32 oh you are right, i missed that in the migration. The OP mentioned that the book will have an attribute though. I will edit my answer to clarify this.